# Administrator Privelege

Tags: root

I just recently installed lubuntu in virtual box and when i tried to install virtual box guest additions, it says that it requires administrative priveleges. So how do i run this program as admin? I am new to linux so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Power-up your virtual machine and wait for it to boot-up. 
When the system is up, go to the menu bar and select Devices -> Install guest add-ons.

[image]

This will mount the add-ons package to your system. A dialog will appear asking what to do with the newly mounted media. Press the Run button.

[image]

A new dialog will appear informing you that you need root privileges and asking for a password. Enter **your** password here and press enter.

[image]

The program will install the guest add-ons.